# How to calculate the pool difficulty based on mining.set_difficulty method from Stratum protocol?

Tags: python, cpu-mining, stratum, difficulty-retargetting

I am trying to build a simple python cpu miner and I have referenced a few other github repos (for learning purposes not for money purposes). I've noticed that many of them simply ignore the `mining.set_difficulty` method when they authorize. I know this is the norm for a CPU miner as a CPU miner can only handle extremely low difficulties.

Many of these python cpu miners are using the block difficulty as the target with a line of code that looks something like this: `target = (curr_block.pool_diff[2:] + '00' * (int(curr_block.pool_diff[:2], 16) - 3)).zfill(64)`

and then checking to see if they meet that target with this line:
`if hash < target:` after hashing and before submitting. I understand this is simpler for lottery mining on a cpu which is a fantasy of an endeavour (as CPU mining in general is I understand)

But my question is this, given this response: `b'{"id":2,"result":true,"error":null}\n{"id":null,"method":"mining.set_difficulty","params":[16384]}` for my `mining.authorize` request from an actual pool how would I adjust the `target` variable to dynamically mine at the difficulty suggested? Is this `16384` number a factor of how many times the original genesis block difficulty I should be mining and is it encoded in hex or something? How should I reformat the `target` variable and account for this in my code?

Thank you for your patience, I am new to this and there are still a lot of things I don't know or understand.